# Nginx 403 error for single file while others work

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, serving

I have a simple Flask/Nginx server and 3 files in location `/opt/hosting/files`:

```
[adam@localhost]$ namei -om /opt/hosting/files
    f: /opt/hosting/files
     dr-xr-xr-x root  root  /
     drwxr-xr-x root  root  opt
     drwxr-xr-x root  root  hosting
     drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx files
```

In the folder `files` I have 3 files: two images and a bigger zip file:

```
[adam@localhost]$ ls -lh /opt/hosting/files/
total 424M
-rwx-----x. 1 nginx nginx  19K 03-06 01:29 file1.jpg
-rwx-----x. 1 nginx nginx  18M 03-06 03:34 file2.png
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx 406M 07-07 13:07 file3.zip
```

I am serving these files and while the first two appear without a problem, I get `403 Forbidden` for the zip file both through www and using wget. I think directories permissions are set correctly, since the two other files are fine. Zip file properties are even higher so this shouldn't be an issue as well.

I tried using `chown root:root` and `chown 777` for file and folders and couldn't access the file anyway. After making changes I'm restarting nginx with `sudo systemctl restart uwsgi`. SELinux shows `Enforcing`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is there any error information returned in the 403 response?

Comment: `403 Forbidden` is what I get through www. Where other can I check it? In Nginx access.log I see `"GET /files/file3.zip HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "http://server-ip/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0" "-"` and in Nginx error.log I can see `2017/07/07 14:22:12 [error] 1691#0: *110 open() "/opt/hosting/files/file3.zip" failed (13: Permission denied)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Reading a [comment by tinesoft here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/403-forbidden-nginx-13-permission-denied) made me check SELinux context of files (yes, I'm running CentOS, forgot to mention that) and it was:

```
[adam@localhost]$ ls -lZ /opt/hosting/files
-rwx-----x. nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 file1.jpg
-rwx-----x. nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 file2.png
-rwxr-xr-x. nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 file3.zip
```

Then, following [SELinux documentation from RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html) I managed to change the type of SELinux context from `user_home_t` to `httpd_sys_content_t` using

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t file3.zip
```

That was it.